# xelatex fail to show characters

Tags: latex, r-markdown, xelatex

when my text has symbols like ( alpha , Beta .. ) they don't appear when I knit pdf, but they do when the output is HTML or anything else.
I tried using xelatex or Luatex as latex_engine but didn't work as well.
does any one have the same issue ? 
this is what I used:

```
---
title: "FILE_NEW"
output:
  pdf_document:
   number_sections: yes
   latex_engine: xelatex
  word_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
toc: yes
toc-depth: 10

---


# Background

I really don't know why symbols don't appear when I knit pdf, this is an example:
IL-1β , IFN-γ
```

this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: did you try `$\alpha$`?

Comment: I did but the problem is that I copy from already prepared text, which has a lot of these characters.

Comment: Can you try with another font? My guess would be that the font you use simply does not have these characters

Comment: I did try and it worked, but I wanted to use the same default font, any suggestions for similar font for paper, or thesis writing ?

Comment: @Sam_9090 If you want the default font, you could use pdflatex and the textgreek package: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\begin{document}

I really don't know why symbols don't appear when I knit pdf, this is an example:
IL-1β , IFN-γ

\end{document}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  do I add this to my metadata ? or how do you implement that in an Rmd file ?

Comment: You could try to change `xelatex` to `pdflatex` and then add `\usepackage{textgreek}` as header-include

Comment: `header-includes: \usepackage{textgreek}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  I tried doing that but still there are some missing files, I presume I need to have other tex from another greek font package, to avoid that I just decided to change the font which is not ideal for me.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  and J_F  thank you both.